# accesing functions from external files bash

Tags: bash, bash-function

This is really simple but since i m still a newbiw in shell scripting, i  not able to do this. It is simple, i have a menu driven script in which when the user enters his choice i loop in the case function and execute the selected menu. Uptil now i was writing the entire code in the same script. Now i am putting the code in each menu option in a external script and accessing the code from there. So it is something like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
. course_func
file=names.dat
[ ! -f $file ] && > $file
while true
do
clear
echo ------------------------------------------
echo 1. Create a record
echo 2. View Records
echo 3. Search for records
echo 4. Delete records that match a pattern
echo ------------------------------------------
echo "Please enter your choice or enter (q) to quit: \c ";read choice
case $choice in
    1)
    create()
    echo Enter to continue; read junk
    ;;
        *)
    clear
    echo Wat nonsense enter properly
    echo Enter to continue: ;read crap
    ;;
esac
done
```

Then i created another external script where I wrote the create() function

Code is in the link,

```
create()
{
  while true
  do
        echo Please enter the name: ;read name
        echo Please enter your surname: ;read surname
        echo Please enter the address: ;read add
        echo Please enter the cell no.: ;read cell
        if yesno Do you really wish to save the following data to file
        then
        echo $name:$surname:$add:$cell >> $file
        clear
        echo The record has been inserted :D
        else 
        echo The record was not save
        fi
        if yesno Do you wish to enter another record
        then
        :
        else
        xit
        fi
  done
}

addRecord()
{

}

search()
{

}

delRecord()
{

}
```

But i am getting an error,

```
course_func: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
course_func: line 31: `}'
menu_driven: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
menu_driven: line 18: ` echo Enter to continue; read junk'
```

Line 31 is where I am ending the addRecord function, which is empty function, for the remaining cases. Can we not have a empty function in bash?

Comment: Images are not how we share text.

Comment: sorry had some issue with the code insertion so added images now i finally found out where i was going wrong

Comment: do not include the parentheses when you invoke a function: `create` not `create()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Functions may not be empty!

--[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 24. Functions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html)

Instead, try:

```
addRecord()
{
    return
}
```

Comment: Yes that resolved the first two errors
course_func: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
course_func: line 31: `}'

Other two errors still persists. I updated the menu_driven code

Comment: Yup got it. Just needed to remove the open and close paranthesis on create. now it is working fine. Thanks @Johnsyweb

Comment: The ABS is a dubious reference, though. Perhaps see instead https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions though I haven't checked if it mentions that function bodies cannot be empty.